# PyroCms is throwing Error 500 when I add a repeater

Tags: php, laravel, repeater, pyrocms

## Issue

I get a Errror 500 when I `add new` to the repeater field (with admin pages).
I cant find how to resolve this, has anyone experienced this issue ?

## System

- PyroCMS 3.7
- Php 7.3
- Homestead

## Background

I created a repeater, then added a repeater page-field to the page, when I try to "add new" on the page I get a Error 500! I get the below error.

## Error in Log

```
[2020-08-10 14:48:50] local.ERROR: Call to a member function getFieldType() on null {"user":1,"email":"user@email.com","url":"https://whsqld.localhost/repeater-field_type/form/184?instance=1&prefix=entry_","identifier":"9fb1bd00-b87c-4a15-ad2a-219a197c17e6","exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalThrowableError(code: 0): Call to a member function getFieldType() on null at /home/vagrant/code/whsqld/vendor/anomaly/streams-platform/src/Entry/EntryModel.php:233)
[stacktrace]
#0 /home/vagrant/code/whsqld/vendor/twig/twig/src/Extension/CoreExtension.php(1499): Anomaly\\Streams\\Platform\\Entry\\EntryModel->getFieldValue('Repository')
#1 /home/vagrant/code/whsqld/storage/framework/views/twig/75/755d6ec9329a9d38b4440a986cd5457175aa8a11b3936377de8097ca51252349.php(58): twig_get_attribute(Object(Anomaly\\Streams\\Platform\\View\\Twig\\Bridge), Object(Twig\\Source), Object(Anomaly\\Streams\\Platform\\Model\\Repeater\\RepeaterRepModEntryModel), 'getFieldValue', Array, 'method', false, false, false, 10)
#2 /home/vagrant/code/whsqld/vendor/twig/twig/src/Template.php(405): __TwigTemplate_c68ceac6b0a4e52a5c83fecc292749a53a76c5566753113acf02d8a73047bec6->doDisplay(Array, Array)
#3 /home/vagrant/code/whsqld/vendor/twig/twig/src/Template.php(378): Twig\\Template->displayWithErrorHandling(Array, Array)
#4 /home/vagrant/code/whsqld/vendor/anomaly/streams-platform/src/View/Twig/Template.php(41): Twig\\Template->display(Array, Array)
#5 /home/vagrant/code/whsqld/storage/framework/views/twig/f6/f6d90bb2c6f5abc06bef7daedd4fc9b4c7ba8ce7926106bdd80452785fcb95a8.php(64): Anomaly\\Streams\\Platform\\View\\Twig\\Template->display(Array)
#6 /home/vagrant/code/whsqld/vendor/twig/twig/src/Template.php(182): __TwigTemplate_1def9219170d34af4cd167a2ddf00081428394dcfe703360175d852375535802->block_content(Array, Array)
#7 /home/vagrant/code/whsqld/storage/framework/views/twig/f6/f6d90bb2c6f5abc06bef7daedd4fc9b4c7ba8ce7926106bdd80452785fcb95a8.php(38): Twig\\Template->displayBlock('content', Array, Array)
#8 /home/vagrant/code/whsqld/vendor/twig/twig/src/Template.php(405): __TwigTemplate_1def9219170d34af4cd167a2ddf00081428394dcfe703360175d852375535802->doDisplay(Array, Array)
#9 /home/vagrant/code/whsqld/vendor/twig/twig/src/Template.php(378): Twig\\Template->displayWithErrorHandling(Array, Array)
#10 /home/vagrant/code/whsqld/vendor/anomaly/streams-platform/src/View/Twig/Template.php(41): Twig\\Template->display(Array, Array)
#11 /home/vagrant/code/whsqld/vendor/twig/twig/src/Template.php(390): Anomaly\\Streams\\Platform\\View\\Twig\\Template->display(Array)
#12 /home/vagrant/code/whsqld/vendor/anomaly/streams-platform/src/View/Twig/Engine.php(88): Twig\\Template->render(Array)
#13 /home/vagrant/code/whsqld/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/View.php(142): Anomaly\\Streams\\Platform\\View\\Twig\\Engine->get('/home/vagrant/c...', Array)
#14 /home/vagrant/code/whsqld/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/View.php(125): Illuminate\\View\\View->getContents()
#15 /home/vagrant/code/whsqld/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/View.php(90): Illuminate\\View\\View->renderContents()
#16 /home/vagrant/code/whsqld/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Http/Response.php(42): Illuminate\\View\\View->render()
#17 /home/vagrant/code/whsqld/vendor/symfony/http-foundation/Response.php(205): Illuminate\\Http\\Response->setContent(Object(Illuminate\\View\\View))
#18 /home/vagrant/code/whsqld/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/ResponseFactory.php(55): Symfony\\Component\\HttpFoundation\\Response->__construct(Object(Illuminate\\View\\View), 200, Array)
#19 /home/vagrant/code/whsqld/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/ResponseFactory.php(81): Illuminate\\Routing\\ResponseFactory->make(Object(Illuminate\\View\\View), 200, Array)
#20 /home/vagrant/code/whsqld/vendor/anomaly/streams-platform/src/Ui/Form/Command/SetFormResponse.php(46): Illuminate\\Routing\\ResponseFactory->view('anomaly.field_t...', Array)
#21 [internal function]: Anomaly\\Streams\\Platform\\Ui\\Form\\Command\\SetFormResponse->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Routing\\ResponseFactory))
#22 /home/vagrant/code/whsqld/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(32): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#23 /home/vagrant/code/whsqld/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(90): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::Illuminate\\Container\\{closure}()
#24 /home/vagrant/code/whsqld/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(34): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::callBoundMethod(Object(Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application), Array, Object(Closure))
#25 /home/vagrant/code/whsqld/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(576): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::call(Object(Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application), Array, Array, NULL)
#26 /home/vagrant/code/whsqld/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Bus/Dispatcher.php(94): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->call(Array)
#27 /home/vagrant/code/whsqld/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(128): Illuminate\\Bus\\Dispatcher->Illuminate\\Bus\\{closure}(Object(Anomaly\\Streams\\Platform\\Ui\\Form\\Command\\SetFormResponse))
#28 /home/vagrant/code/whsqld/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(104): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Anomaly\\Streams\\Platform\\Ui\\Form\\Command\\SetFormResponse))
#29 /home/vagrant/code/whsqld/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Bus/Dispatcher.php(98): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#30 /home/vagrant/code/whsqld/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bus/DispatchesJobs.php(28): Illuminate\\Bus\\Dispatcher->dispatchNow(Object(Anomaly\\Streams\\Platform\\Ui\\Form\\Command\\SetFormResponse))
#31 /home/vagrant/code/whsqld/vendor/anomaly/streams-platform/src/Ui/Form/FormBuilder.php(328): Anomaly\\Streams\\Platform\\Ui\\Form\\FormBuilder->dispatchNow(Object(Anomaly\\Streams\\Platform\\Ui\\Form\\Command\\SetFormResponse))
#32 /home/vagrant/code/whsqld/core/anomaly/repeater-field_type/src/Http/Controller/RepeaterController.php(37): Anomaly\\Streams\\Platform\\Ui\\Form\\FormBuilder->render()
#33 [internal function]: Anomaly\\RepeaterFieldType\\Http\\Controller\\RepeaterController->form(Object(Anomaly\\Streams\\Platform\\Field\\FieldRepository), Object(Anomaly\\Streams\\Platform\\Field\\FieldModel))
#34 /home/vagrant/code/whsqld/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Controller.php(54): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#35 /home/vagrant/code/whsqld/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/ControllerDispatcher.php(45): Illuminate\\Routing\\Controller->callAction('form', Array)
#36 /home/vagrant/code/whsqld/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php(219): Illuminate\\Routing\\ControllerDispatcher->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\\Routing\\Route), Object(Anomaly\\RepeaterFieldType\\Http\\Controller\\RepeaterController), 'form')
#37 /home/vagrant/code/whsqld/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php(176): Illuminate\\Routing\\Route->runController()
#38 /home/vagrant/code/whsqld/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(680): Illuminate\\Routing\\Route->run()
#39 /home/vagrant/code/whsqld/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(30): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#40 /home/vagrant/code/whsqld/vendor/anomaly/streams-platform/src/Http/Middleware/CheckForMaintenanceMode.php(91): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#41 /home/vagrant/code/whsqld/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(163): Anomaly\\Streams\\Platform\\Http\\Middleware\\CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#42 /home/vagrant/code/whsqld/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#43 /home/vagrant/code/whsqld/vendor/anomaly/streams-platform/src/Http/Middleware/HttpCache.php(88): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#44 /home/vagrant/code/whsqld/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(163): Anomaly\\Streams\\Platform\\Http\\Middleware\\HttpCache->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#45 /home/vagrant/code/whsqld/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#46 /home/vagrant/code/whsqld/core/anomaly/redirects-module/src/Http/Middleware/RedirectDomains.php(32): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#47 /home/vagrant/code/whsqld/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(163): Anomaly\\RedirectsModule\\Http\\Middleware\\RedirectDomains->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#48 /home/vagrant/code/whsqld/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#49 /home/vagrant/code/whsqld/core/anomaly/users-module/src/Http/Middleware/AuthorizeRoutePermission.php(117): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#50 /home/vagrant/code/whsqld/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(163): Anomaly\\UsersModule\\Http\\Middleware\\AuthorizeRoutePermission->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#51 /home/vagrant/code/whsqld/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#52 /home/vagrant/code/whsqld/core/anomaly/users-module/src/Http/Middleware/AuthorizeControlPanel.php(44): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#53 /home/vagrant/code/whsqld/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(163): Anomaly\\UsersModule\\Http\\Middleware\\AuthorizeControlPanel->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#54 /home/vagrant/code/whsqld/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#55 /home/vagrant/code/whsqld/core/anomaly/users-module/src/Http/Middleware/AuthorizeModuleAccess.php(54): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#56 /home/vagrant/code/whsqld/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(163): Anomaly\\UsersModule\\Http\\Middleware\\AuthorizeModuleAccess->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#57 /home/vagrant/code/whsqld/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#58 /home/vagrant/code/whsqld/core/anomaly/users-module/src/Http/Middleware/AuthorizeRouteRoles.php(101): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#59 /home/vagrant/code/whsqld/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(163): Anomaly\\UsersModule\\Http\\Middleware\\AuthorizeRouteRoles->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#60 /home/vagrant/code/whsqld/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#61 /home/vagrant/code/whsqld/core/anomaly/users-module/src/Http/Middleware/CheckSecurity.php(47): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#62 /home/vagrant/code/whsqld/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(163): Anomaly\\UsersModule\\Http\\Middleware\\CheckSecurity->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#63 /home/vagrant/code/whsqld/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#64 /home/vagrant/code/whsqld/core/anomaly/installer-module/src/Http/Middleware/CheckIfInstallerExists.php(72): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#65 /home/vagrant/code/whsqld/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(163): Anomaly\\InstallerModule\\Http\\Middleware\\CheckIfInstallerExists->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#66 /home/vagrant/code/whsqld/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#67 /home/vagrant/code/whsqld/vendor/anomaly/streams-platform/src/Http/Middleware/ApplicationReady.php(34): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#68 /home/vagrant/code/whsqld/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(163): Anomaly\\Streams\\Platform\\Http\\Middleware\\ApplicationReady->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#69 /home/vagrant/code/whsqld/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#70 /home/vagrant/code/whsqld/vendor/anomaly/streams-platform/src/Http/Middleware/CheckLocale.php(32): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#71 /home/vagrant/code/whsqld/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(163): Anomaly\\Streams\\Platform\\Http\\Middleware\\CheckLocale->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#72 /home/vagrant/code/whsqld/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#73 /home/vagrant/code/whsqld/vendor/anomaly/streams-platform/src/Http/Middleware/SetLocale.php(114): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#74 /home/vagrant/code/whsqld/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(163): Anomaly\\Streams\\Platform\\Http\\Middleware\\SetLocale->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#75 /home/vagrant/code/whsqld/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#76 /home/vagrant/code/whsqld/vendor/anomaly/streams-platform/src/Http/Middleware/PrefixDomain.php(71): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#77 /home/vagrant/code/whsqld/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(163): Anomaly\\Streams\\Platform\\Http\\Middleware\\PrefixDomain->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#78 /home/vagrant/code/whsqld/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#79 /home/vagrant/code/whsqld/vendor/anomaly/streams-platform/src/Http/Middleware/ForceSsl.php(49): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#80 /home/vagrant/code/whsqld/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(163): Anomaly\\Streams\\Platform\\Http\\Middleware\\ForceSsl->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#81 /home/vagrant/code/whsqld/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#82 /home/vagrant/code/whsqld/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php(75): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#83 /home/vagrant/code/whsqld/vendor/anomaly/streams-platform/src/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php(80): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\VerifyCsrfToken->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#84 /home/vagrant/code/whsqld/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(163): Anomaly\\Streams\\Platform\\Http\\Middleware\\VerifyCsrfToken->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#85 /home/vagrant/code/whsqld/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#86 /home/vagrant/code/whsqld/vendor/anomaly/streams-platform/src/Http/Middleware/PoweredBy.php(26): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#87 /home/vagrant/code/whsqld/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(163): Anomaly\\Streams\\Platform\\Http\\Middleware\\PoweredBy->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#88 /home/vagrant/code/whsqld/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#89 /home/vagrant/code/whsqld/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(104): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#90 /home/vagrant/code/whsqld/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(682): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#91 /home/vagrant/code/whsqld/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(657): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->runRouteWithinStack(Object(Illuminate\\Routing\\Route), Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#92 /home/vagrant/code/whsqld/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(623): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->runRoute(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Illuminate\\Routing\\Route))
#93 /home/vagrant/code/whsqld/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(612): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->dispatchToRoute(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#94 /home/vagrant/code/whsqld/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(176): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#95 /home/vagrant/code/whsqld/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(30): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#96 /home/vagrant/code/whsqld/vendor/anomaly/streams-platform/src/Http/Middleware/ProxySession.php(32): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#97 /home/vagrant/code/whsqld/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(163): Anomaly\\Streams\\Platform\\Http\\Middleware\\ProxySession->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#98 /home/vagrant/code/whsqld/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#99 /home/vagrant/code/whsqld/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Middleware/AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php(37): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#100 /home/vagrant/code/whsqld/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(163): Illuminate\\Cookie\\Middleware\\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#101 /home/vagrant/code/whsqld/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
```

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: theres no custom code, this is the built in repeater for pyrocms that I configured

Comment: You may want to run `streams:cleanup` and `streams:compile`. It looks like a misconfigured or abandoned field. Does the control panel show any weirdness? Code and stream structure would indeed be super helpful.

Comment: I think you are right, the issue went away with the streams:cleanup and recompile. Thanks again Ryan!

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely a misconfigured field, however would need to see the declaring code to know for sure.